# Redirect http to https in Hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I do have the following configuration for my hapi server

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();

const tls = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../certificates/cert.crt')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../certificates/cert.key')),
};

server.connection({
  port: process.env.PORT_HTTP || 80,
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
});

server.connection({
  port: process.env.PORT_HTTPS || 443,
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
  tls,
});
```

The server is working ok on both, `http` and `https`, but I would like to redirect all the traffic from the `http` to `https`.

How should I proceed, tried already to register the `hapi-require-https` npm module but the traffic still remain the same, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an extra server for http requests and bind them to `redirect` function.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var http = new Hapi.Server(80);
var server = new Hapi.Server(443, { tls: {} });

var redirect = function () {

    this.reply.redirect('https://your.site/' + this.params.path);
});

http.route({ method: '*', path: '/{path*}', handler: redirect });
```

Update(other option)

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/', 
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        if(request.headers.referer.split(':')[0] == "http"){
           this.reply.redirect('https://your.site' + this.params.path);
        }
    }
});
```

How about this? Binding them both

```
var http = new Hapi.Server(80); // our extra server
http.route({ 
method: '*', 
path: '/{path*}', 
handler: 
      function (request, reply) {

       // if(request.headers.referer.split(':')[0] == "http"){
           this.reply.redirect('https://your.site' + this.params.path);
       // }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using hapi `16.5.2` the above constructor does not work I am getting `Invalid server options "value" must be an object`

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru try this, this might work, you are basically checking the headers to see if it's http or https, then you are redirecting in the case

Comment: Checking this for every route ? I thought something as a plugin maybe, but it seems I should have 2 connections... I should merge your 2 responses somehow...

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru oh, yes, you should, nice thinking. that's what I thought would be a problem too, maybe there's a way to handle all the requests in a route ? something like `server.all()`

Comment: Please check the update and let me know @AlexandruOlaru

Comment: Seems to work, but need to create to servers, one for http and on for https.

Comment: Any clues for extending for things such as CloudFoundry where everything actually terminates HTTP (internal) after hitting a platform wide HTTPS / TLS terminator?

Answer (score 2):

Create two server instances to handle http & https traffic seperately.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server(80);
var httpsServer = new Hapi.Server(443, { tls: { // your certificates here} });
```

Now register the [hapi-gate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-gate) plugin to the base server so that it redirects the traffic to https.

```
server.register({
  register: require('hapi-gate'),
  options: {https: true} // will force https on all requests
});
```

You can also use the hapi-require-https plugin instead.

Comment: Does the hapi-gate handle things such as CloudFoundry where everything actually terminates http (internal) after hitting a platform wide HTTPS / TLS terminator?